# How to position tooltip top center of path? SVG Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

New to javascript and trying to position tooltip top center of element/path on SVG map. Currently, the tooltip follows the `.mousemove` but would like it to be fixed top center, preferably with a slight offset so it barely overlaps the selected area.

Here is the code on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwalker005/a8vrmw06/

```js
$("path, polygon").hover(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','block');
  $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
});

$("path, polygon").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','none');
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('top',e.pageY-$('#info-box').height()-40);
  $('#info-box').css('left',e.pageX-($('#info-box').width())/2);
}).mouseover();

var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if(ios) {
  $('abbr').on('click touchend', function() { 
    var link = $(this).attr('href');   
    window.open(link,'_blank');
    return false;
  });
}
```

```css
#map-example{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


path:hover, polygon:hover {
  fill: #20487c !important;

}

#info-box {
  background-color: #333;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #3498DB;  
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  font-family: arial;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#info-box:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #3498DB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="info-box"></div>

<svg version="1.1" id="map-example" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 300 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="area 01" data-info="<div>Area 01:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M90.5,72.5v12l7,1v12h20l3-27C120.5,70.5,108,77,90.5,72.5z"/>
<path id="area 02" data-info="<div>Area 02:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M89,72v14l7,1v12h21v17l-23-2l-11-6V93c0,0-6-7-16-5l5-33C72,55,80,59,89,72z"/>
<polygon id="area 03" data-info="<div>Area 03:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" points="120,87 119,97 119,112 138,120 155,108 155,93 136,83 "/>
<polygon id="area 04" data-info="<div>Area 04:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" points="138,122 143,131 146,129 152,137 155,135 159,138 159,152 174,146 199,131 
 225,117 219,108 199,108 170,101 157,94 156.5,108.5 "/>
<path id="area 05" data-info="<div>Area 05:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M122,70l-2,15l17-4l33,18l15,3l15-9l-21-29l-5,3l-17-19c0,0-16,10-22,15
 C127.9,68.9,122,70,122,70z"/>
<path id="area 06" data-info="<div>Area 06:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M158,47.2l16.8,18.1l4.9-3l22.7,31.2l-15.8,10L198,106l22.7,1l5.3,9l12-6l7.5-27.1
 l-4.9-20.1l-24.7-32.2c0,0-7.9-8-20.8-1l-3-3C192.1,26.6,175,36,158,47.2z"/>
<polygon id="area 07" data-info="<div>Area 07:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" points="102,117 101,139 93,145 95,150 95,156 90,156 87,150 83,150 83,157 73,157 
 73,154 78,150 70,137 67,139 65,134 67,130 75.5,129.5 79.5,122.5 83.5,110.5 94.5,116.5 "/>
<polygon id="area 08" data-info="<div>Area 08:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" points="81,95 81,108 78,121 74,128 65,128 63,132 54,132 54,128 40,127 40,122 
 43,122 47,117 51,117 51,110 56,110 56,95 63,95 67,90 70,90 77,91 "/>
<polygon id="area 09" data-info="<div>Area 09:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" points="104,118 119,118 119,114 135,121 142,133 146,131 151,138 147,141 141,136 
 120,150 104,137 "/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you use a `mouseleave` handler to hide the tooltip and a `mousemove` handler to make th tooltip follow the mouse...

Comment all that up.

To each `polygon` and `path`, add a data attribute. Like, for example:

```
<path id="area 01" data-tooltip-left="33" data-tooltip-top="22" data-info="<div>Area 01:</div><div>More Info about area</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M90.5,72.5v12l7,1v12h20l3-27C120.5,70.5,108,77,90.5,72.5z"/>
```

Then modify your `hover` handler like this:

```
var timeout;
$("path, polygon").hover(
  function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    console.log($(this)[0].tagName);
    $('#info-box').css({
      'display':'block',
      'position':'fixed',
      'top':$(this).offset().top + parseInt($(this).data("tooltip-top")),  // 22px added
      'left':$(this).offset().left + parseInt($(this).data("tooltip-left"))  // 33px added
    });
    $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
  },
  function(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      $('#info-box').css('display','none');
    },1000);
  });
```

The `timeout` variable is just to prevent the dribble effect if the mouse comes across the tooltip.

The first function in the `.hover()` handler is the `mouseenter` action. The second one is the `mouseleave` action.

Notice the timeout is instantiated on mouseleave only... And "disabled" or resetted" on `mouseenter` to prevent dribbling.

**Now, about "centering"...** Since your polygons have irregular shapes, this can be hard. But using the data attributes, shape by shape... There is something that can be done.

Your fun begins there.
;)

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/b29u5La8/) (Without that centering aspect)

[**Last Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/j47p3bu0/) (With a centering solution... Look for "Area 06")

**EDIT**
There was a "resize" aspect... And the SVG size is not linearly liked to the tooltip size. While fighting with it, I got sick of Fiddle stupidly bugging all the time, so I continued on this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jYmobX?editors=1011) where I'm close...

Comment: Since those share really are irregular, I would use some arbitrary [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) attributes for each. like `data-tooltip-left="33"` and `data-tooltip-top="44"` to add to the `$(this).offset()` value... Like said. Fun is there!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Louys Patrice Bessette! Please forgive me for my limited knowledge on jquery. I'm starting to think this may be too advanced for me since they are all irregular shapes and will be harder to center. Please bear with me, how exactly would I add `this.getBoundingClientRect().width;` ?

Comment: Nahh.. Forget about getbounding stuff... It only will get you the rectangle dimensions of the shape container. That was my first idea (but a bad one). Instead, look for data attributes and position them one by one by hand at your taste.

Comment: Look for "Area 06" in this other [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/mw6hbmuw/) ;) mmm... The other areas are buggy since the data attr aren't defined. Let me edit that to prevent a useless bug.

Comment: Haa... Here is better. So in this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/j47p3bu0/), even if there is a shape with undefined data attribute intended to position the tooltip, there is no error and all works fine.

Comment: Making the changes, thank you so much! However, now it looks like the tooltip doesn't disappear after leaving the path(s). Not sure if I'm missing something?

Comment: I have noticed that when I resize the window the position of the tooltip changes/moves. Is there a way to keep the tooltip position the same no matter the window size.

Comment: Ok... The tooltip is aligned on the svg element container by its top/left corner... On the top/left corner of the svg element. Now that tootip does not "resize" at the same ratio than the SVG... And that was the horrible problem to solve. Have a look at this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jYmobX?editors=1011) where I'm close to something good. I leave you the perfectionnist artwork.. ;)